INVALID_ARGUMENT error on YoutubeDataApi PlaylistItem:update
Since the end of May, error occurs has suddenly occurred when executing the YouTube data API (PlaylistItem:update).
Until then, there was no error.
[Request]
{
    "id": "*correct id*",
    "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "*correct playlistId*",
        "resourceId": {
            "kind": "youtube#video",
            "videoId": "*correct videoId*"
        },
        position:0
    }
}

[Response(Error)]
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}


Trying on a different playlist　-> Same error occurs.
Execute other API　-> PlaylistItem:list no error occurs.


Consider to post your full request on Issue Tracker - it might be a bug.
